# vim, fast same line function brackets

Tags: vim, curly-braces

Is there a quick way to open curly brackets for a function and end in insert mode indented on the next line. So for example:

```
void myFunc(int arg) {
    <cursor>
}
```

Specifically, I’m asking for a motion to execute after writing the arguments inside `()`.

Right now the only way I can think is the direct way, insert both open and closed curly brackets, move the second one down two lines, move up one and then tab.
`{}<esc>i<enter><enter><esc>ki<tab>`

This seems really redundant. I guess I can also wait to write the second curly after creating the new lines and save a mode switch. But is there a smarter vim-er way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create a custom mapping

   If the manual way is to do:

   ```
   {}<Esc>i<CR><CR>
   ```

   then you can map it to something shorter:

   ```
   inoremap {<CR> {}<Esc>i<CR><CR>
   ```

   and also do it for other brackets:

   ```
   inoremap {<CR> {}<Esc>i<CR><CR>
   inoremap (<CR> ()<Esc>i<CR><CR>
   " etc.
   ```

   That approach is very common. Here is a variant I've had in my `vimrc` for many years:

   ```
   inoremap (; (<CR>);<C-c>O
   " etc.
   ```
2. Use a third-party plugin

   Just google for "vim auto close brackets".

Comment: Instead of all the `<esc>i`, `<c-g>U<left>` is much better (since vim 7.4.849) as it will support redo.

Comment: Indeed but the question is not about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<cr><c-c>O` instead of the double `<cr><cr><up>`: this will ensure the cursor will be correctly indented at the end.

`<cr><cr><up><c-f>` would have worked as long as CTRL-F is present in [`'indentkeys'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27indentkeys%27). As such, `<c-c>O` is more robust.

Note: I would recommend using a bracketing plugin though as these mappings without  mappings that helps jumping out of bracket-pairs can be really cumbersome to use. Also these plugins already know how to support  [`redo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#redo)/[`.`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%2e), and many other things.

Comment: Using `<C-c>` instead of `<Esc>` would be even better because it doesn't trigger `InsertLeave` and thus reduces possible side-effects.